# How to replace centered text in a PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I use the `PDFTextReplacement` example.
It does the replacement as expected, In case my text is left aligned.
But if my input pdf has a text centered, it replaces the text as a left aligned.
Ok, so I have to recalculate the right starting point.

For that reason I have two targets or questions:

- How to determine the alignment?
- How to calculate the right starting point?

Here is my code:

```
public PDDocument doIt(String inputFile, Map<String, String> text)
        throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;

    doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
    List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
        PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
        PDStream contents = page.getContents();

        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
        parser.parse();
        List tokens = parser.getTokens();
        for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
            Object next = tokens.get(j);

            if (next instanceof PDFOperator) {

                PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;

                // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display
                // strings in a PDF

                String pstring = "";
                int prej = 0;
                if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj")) {
                    // Tj takes one operator and that is the string
                    // to display so lets update that operator
                    COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    String string = previous.getString();
                    // System.out.println(j + " " + string);
                    if (j == prej) {
                        pstring += string;
                    } else {
                        prej = j;
                        pstring = string;
                    }

                    previous.reset();
                    previous.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                } else if (op.getOperation().equals("TJ")) {
                    COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                        Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                        if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                            COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                            String string = cosString.getString();

                            if (j == prej) {
                                pstring += string;
                            } else {
                                prej = j;
                                pstring = string;
                            }

                            cosString.reset();
                            // cosString.append(string
                            // .getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                        }

                    }

                    COSString cosString2 = (COSString) previous
                            .getObject(0);

                    for (int t = 1; t < previous.size(); t++)
                        previous.remove(t);

                    // cosString2.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);

                    if (text.containsKey(pstring.trim())) {

                        String textValue = text.get(pstring.trim());
                        cosString2.append(textValue.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

                        for (int k = 1; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                            previous.remove(k);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        // now that the tokens are updated we will replace the
        // page content stream.
        PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
        OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
        ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
        tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
        page.setContents(updatedStream);
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: *How to determine the alignment* - PDF does not know alignment. It draws a text starting at the current origin, that's all. You can try to determine an alignment by comparing the position of the text of the current "line" with the page dimensions and the position of text on the "lines" before and after ("line" because PDF does not necessarily follow a text line concept). But if some text looks centered, are you sure it was intended to be centered? It may also have merely been indented some distance and by chance now *look centered*.

Comment: @mkl Yes this s exactly that what I have seen in the PDDocument. So I have to refine my questions. 1. So how to get the exact space used by the content (icepdf uses lineText.getBounds() ) ? 2. how to calaculate the used space for new strings (based on BASE14 Fonts) )

Comment: Your code works on a very low level, it inspects individual instructions from the page content streams. Thus, it does not benefit from higher level features. This especially means that on that level you have to follow up on the changes of the current graphic state yourself. To be able to do so, you should study the [PDF specification ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) first, especially the chapters 8 (to understand how the graphic state changes) and 9 (to understand how text is drawn).

Comment: Most of this coding already has been done in PDFBox, though. `PDFStreamEngine` walks through the instructions from the page content stream and calls `processTextPosition` with text chunks and their position and dimension. So on that level you eventually get the dimensions you ask for. Unfortunately you are quite far removed from the actual page content stream you want to manipulate. Thus, you'll have to tweak that class somewhat for you to have both the low-level instructions and the high-level interpretation available in a synchronized manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function:

```
 public void doIt( String inputFile, String outputFile, String strToFind, String message)
            throws IOException, COSVisitorException
        {
            // the document
            PDDocument doc = null;
            try
            {
                doc = PDDocument.load( inputFile );
                List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
                for( int i=0; i<pages.size(); i++ )
                {
                    PDPage page = (PDPage)pages.get( i );
                    PDStream contents = page.getContents();
                    PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream() );
                    parser.parse();
                    List tokens = parser.getTokens();
                    for( int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++ )
                    {
                        Object next = tokens.get( j );
                        if( next instanceof PDFOperator )
                        {
                            PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator)next;
                            //Tj and TJ are the two operators that display
                            //strings in a PDF
                            if( op.getOperation().equals( "Tj" ) )
                            {
                                //Tj takes one operator and that is the string
                                //to display so lets update that operator
                                COSString previous = (COSString)tokens.get( j-1 );
                                String string = previous.getString();
                                string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                                previous.reset();
                                previous.append( string.getBytes() );
                            }
                            else if( op.getOperation().equals( "TJ" ) )
                            {
                                COSArray previous = (COSArray)tokens.get( j-1 );
                                for( int k=0; k<previous.size(); k++ )
                                {
                                    Object arrElement = previous.getObject( k );
                                    if( arrElement instanceof COSString )
                                    {
                                        COSString cosString = (COSString)arrElement;
                                        String string = cosString.getString();
                                        string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                                        cosString.reset();
                                        cosString.append( string.getBytes() );
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //now that the tokens are updated we will replace the
                    //page content stream.
                    PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
                    OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
                    ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
                    tokenWriter.writeTokens( tokens );
                    page.setContents( updatedStream );
                }
                doc.save( outputFile );
            }
            finally
            {
                if( doc != null )
                {
                    doc.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where exactly does your code try to determine the alignment of the original line? Let alone re-align the changed line?

Comment: don't use the alignement, just make some kind of marker like _TEXTHERE inside your pdf and replace it with the replave function

Comment: But the op explicitly wanted to retain a special alignment, he wanted centered text after replacing.